# Matlab - wden function don't work with some famlies

Tags: matlab, noise

I am using the function [wden](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wden.html) for denoising signals,

but I found that there are some wavelet families didn't work with this function

like Gaussian family, Mexican hat family and more

can anyone help me why this happened?

and is there another way to use these families for denoising?

Comment: from documentation, `wden` works for Gaussian noise ?!

Comment: No, No, I mean Gaussian wavelet family don't work with this function not with Gaussian noise